# How to assign a value to a model in Simple_Forms (Ruby on Rails)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Here's a snippet from a form I have. Assigning the :title and :description is working just fine when creating a model "Post", however when I try and assign the category_id as 1 it doesn't assign anything, the category_id remains as nil.

```
.form-group
        = f.input :title, input_html: { class: 'form-control' }

.form-group
        = f.input :description, input_html: { class: 'form-control' }

.form-group
        = f.input :category_id, input_html: { class: 'form-control' }
```

---

When using Post.find_by(title: 'posty' (a title I gave to the post))
I get...

```
 => #<Post id: 13, title: "posty", description: "eyyyyyy", created_at: "2016-03-07 17:45:05", updated_at: "2016-03-07 17:45:05", category_id: nil>
```

Notice how category_id: nil? It should equal the number which was assigned in the forms, but it isn't working.

Here's a snippet from the Schema.rb. It contains 2 models, categories and posts, posts belongs to a category.

```
  create_table "categories", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  create_table "posts", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "title"
    t.text     "description"
    t.datetime "created_at",  null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",  null: false
    t.integer  "category_id"
  end

  add_index "posts", ["category_id"], name: "index_posts_on_category_id"
```

---

Here is my posts_controller code

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
    before_action :find_post, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

    def index
        @posts = Post.all.order("created_at DESC")
    end

    def show
    end

    def new
        @post = Post.new
    end

    def create
        @post = Post.new(post_params)

        if @post.save
          redirect_to @post, notice: "Successfully created"
        else
          render 'new'
        end
    end

    def edit
    end

    def update
        if @post.update(post_params)
            redirect_to @post, notice: "Post was successfully updated"
        else
            render 'edit'
        end
    end

    def destroy
        @post.destroy
        redirect_to root_path
    end

    private

    def post_params
        params.require(:post).permit(:title, :description)
    end

    def find_post
        @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    end

end
```

Comment: Add your `posts_controller.rb` code.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot. I'm still really new to this.

Comment: Got it, I fixed it. Thanks for reminding me.

Answer (score 0):

In `posts_controller.rb`, change:

```
def post_params
    params.require(:post).permit(:title, :description)
end
```

to:

```
def post_params
    params.require(:post).permit(:title, :description, :category_id)
end
```

Comment: Hey, thanks. I figured it out after someone reminded me of the posts_controller, I then edited my answer as to not upset an further people trying to answer the question. Again, thank you.